# Read and write values from a Class in arduino IDE

Tags: c++, class, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm using a timer library which has a function that takes a void function as parameter to execute it after a certain time. I want to use a function that writes a value on a digital PIN depending on the device I initialize in a variable.

I thought I could use a class to store a specific pin and from the class read the pin and use the function that reads the pin from the class, rather than passing a parameter to the function since the timer library doesn't accept void functions with parameters.

```
class output_control{
  int pin;
  void output_on();
 };

void output_control::output_on(){
digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);  //Just an example 
}
```

What I'm having trouble is declaring an array with 10 "devices" with this class and then assigning a value to the integer variable "pin" that I made in the class.

```
output_control device[10];
device.pin[1]=6;
device.pin[2]=5;
```

I think I'm misunderstanding classes,the IDE outputs the error: "request for member 'pin' in 'device', which is of non-class type 'output_control[10]', what I want is able to read from variables I created in the class so the void function I created is able to read those values to run certain actions with them and write values on the variables of the class so I can use them in certain tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It can get tricky using classes with Arduino/Wiring since, to simplify things for us, there is stuff that goes on at compile time which is not obvious (and not like using straight C++).

For your task, writing a function to set the pin should work (and good practice - the whole encapsulation thing). The code below compiles (though I haven't run it).

Careful with classes on Arduino though - there isn't much memory to play with so sometimes, the cleaner, more obvious approach won't work and one needs to resort to storing things in arrays and using lots of variables.

```
class output_control{

public:
  void  output_on(){
    digitalWrite(_pin,HIGH);  //Just an example 
  }
  void  setPin(int p){
    _pin = p;
  }

  private:
   int _pin;
};


output_control device[10]; // declare the array of objects

void setup(){
  //init the variables
  device[0].setPin(6);
  device[1].setPin(7);
}

void loop(){
 // do some stuff


}
```